# Configurable JS Conflict

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, jquery

My problem is that only few configurable products have JS error on their page while its still same format just different description, price etc. The product tabs are not working and the content of all 3 tabs is shown straight away as well as the menu is not functioning. The error I could get from Firebug is:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 23 of the JSON data
...trim(b);if(a.JSON&&a.JSON.parse)return a.JSON.parse(b);if(n.test(b.replace(o,"@"...
```

If I create a configurable product and not link associated products its okay, same for the simple products individual pages but when I associate them and try to view it again this problem arises, even though other configurable products are shown correctly.

I thought of some illegal char inside description etc but couldn't find something, any ideas?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the bug so I thought to share it with everyone for later reference, I used the quote character "" as well as () on the configurable attributes which caused this error. Removing them and replacing quote with the word inches fixed it.

Comment: It is okay to accept your own answer, and thanks for returning to add your findings for those who may also have similar issues.